# Select Objects having all types of another Object

Tags: sql, oracle, having

I have a SQL exercise for a car rental agency.

A vehicle has a category and an agency. I need to find the list of agencies having all categories of vehicle.

I made this request, but my referent told me that it was not optimized at all and that it could be simpler.

```
SELECT A.CODE_AG
FROM VEHICULE V
INNER JOIN AGENCE A on A.CODE_AG = V.CODE_AG
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CODE_CATEG) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM CATEGORIE)
GROUP BY A.CODE_AG;
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL? Don't add tags for databases you're not using.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with it.

Comment: sorry, i wouldnt add mysql

Comment: You do not need `AGENCE` table as `CODE_AG` is available in `VEHICULE`. But to answer the question your referent should tell what is the issue with the current code.